Orthogonal direct sum typeset (with hat)

i.e. I would like this as orthogonal direct sum, which is a specific one. Since there is no any post about this, can anyone help? NO $\widehat$, please. Thanks.

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$U_1 \mathbin{\hat\oplus}\dots\mathbin{\hat\oplus}U_m$
\end{document}


If you don't like the look of \oplus, then make your own:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\stackMath
\newcommand\mysym{\mathbin{\hat{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\scriptstyle+}{\scalebox{.8}{$\bigcirc$}}}}}
\begin{document}
$U_1 \mysym\dots\mysym U_m$
\end{document}



It works perfectly fine. Give you credits.

A construct such as \hat{\oplus} produce an Acc atom that, for the purpose of spacing, is considered the same as an Ord atom. So you need to reinstate the desired atom type.
I suggest defining a macro for it.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\orthsum}{\mathbin{\hat{\oplus}}}

\begin{document}

\[
U_1\orthsum \dots \orthsum U_m
\]

\end{document}

You can see that the symbol behaves correctly with respect to \dots, which should be centered in this case, not at the baseline.

Why a macro? Because you can easily change it to anything else. A common notation for orthogonal direct sums is with ⊞
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%\newcommand{\orthsum}{\mathbin{\hat{\oplus}}}
\newcommand{\orthsum}{\DOTSB\boxplus}

\begin{document}

\[
U_1\orthsum \dots \orthsum U_m
\]

\end{document}


OK, this needs some work to get it right.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%\newcommand{\orthsum}{\mathbin{\hat{\oplus}}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\orthsum}{\DOTSB\mathbin{\mathpalette\boxplus@\relax}}
\newcommand{\boxplus@}[2]{\vcenter{\hbox{$\m@th#1\boxplus$}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
U_1\oplus \dots \oplus U_m
\\
U_1\orthsum \dots \orthsum U_m
\end{gather*}

\end{document}


If you prefer for \oplus the same style as the image, you can import the symbol from mathabx.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> matha5
  <5.5-6.5> matha6
  <6.5-7.5> matha7
  <7.5-8.5> matha8
  <8.5-9.5> matha9
  <9.5-11> matha10
  <11-> matha12
}{}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathb5
  <5.5-6.5> mathb6
  <6.5-7.5> mathb7
  <7.5-8.5> mathb8
  <8.5-9.5> mathb9
  <9.5-11> mathb10
  <11-> mathb12
}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oplus}{2}{matha}{"60}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\boxplus}{2}{mathb}{"60}

\newcommand{\orthsum}{\mathbin{\hat{\oplus}}}
%\newcommand{\orthsum}{\DOTSB\boxplus}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
U_1\oplus \dots \oplus U_m
\\
U_1\orthsum \dots \orthsum U_m
\end{gather*}

\end{document}


If you switch the comments for \orthsum you get

